# Is it possible to hide links in a links webpart based on a group?

Tags: web-part, links-list

Is it possible to hide links in a links webpart based on a group? I am trying to filter a list based on the user login permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create item level permissions on the Links list urls. This will trim the results based on the logged in user when displayed in a web part by selecting Item Level Permissions from the ribbon or the drop down menu when you have an item selected.

You could obscure the links by using audience targetting, users could wind up seeing them so don't confuse targetting with security if they lead to sensitive places/files.